# How to uncheck with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have a list of rows like the image below. When you click on multiple checkboxes to choose multiple rows, the `selectedIds` are passed down to the PostBulkActionButtons as a prop.

[image]

This is my PostBulkActionButtons component:

```
export default function PostBulkActionButtons(props) {
    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
    const ids = props.selectedIds;
    useEffect(() => {
        ids.map((id) => {
            async function fetchData(id) {
                const res = await ajax.getMealPlan(id);
                setRecipes((recipes) => [...recipes, res.data.data]);
            }
            fetchData(id);
        });
    }, [ids]);
    
    return <div>{recipes}</div>;
}
```

The problem is when I uncheck a row, the recipes still contain the unchecked row. I know the code above generates duplicates of rows on every select, and I have managed to solve that!
Any suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this, Hope it helps**

```
export default function PostBulkActionButtons(props) {
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
const ids = props.selectedIds;
useEffect(() => {
    ids.map((id) => {
        async function fetchData(id) {
            const res = await ajax.getMealPlan(id);
            const data = res.filter(i => i === recipes);
            setRecipes((recipes) => [...recipes, data]);
        }
        fetchData(id);
    });
}, [ids]);

return <div>{recipes}</div>;
```

Comment: Thanks, but `res.data.data` is not an array, it is an object like this 
{id: 9,
note: "For Lunch",
recipe_objs: [{…}]}

Comment: change it to just res than as it is an array of objects edited the code

Answer (score 0):

When you do `setRecipes((recipes) => [...recipes, res.data.data]);` you are never deleting data from the `recipes` array, only adding. You need to filter the array, in order to remove the unchecked ids.